# Extract segment from a file between two given positions in bash

Tags: bash, awk

How to extract a segment from a file between two given positions?

E.g.

given a file `letter.txt` as below:

```
a b c d e f
```

Given two positions `1 6`, how to get the following new file `result.txt`:

```
a b c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
cut -c1-6 letter.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,6)}' letter.txt
```

Using shell:

```
while read line
do
  echo ${line:0:6}
done < letter.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the somewhat obscure [colrm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/colrm.1.html) command

```
colrm 7 <letter.txt
a b c
```

Comment: I try on Solaris, but can't find the command, what env do you run it?